# Avoid queries concatenation when redirecting few times in a row

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm working in an Express application and experiencing a strange behaviour.

I'm displaying error messages when there is something that goes wrong.

> */app/edit/username?e=error1*

It seems that after two errors happen in a row, the queries somehow concatenate:

> *app/edit/username?e=error1?e=error2*

I would like to avoid that to happen and display only error 2:

> *app/edit/username?e=error2*

I'm using Express redirect:

```
return res.redirect('/app/edit/' + username + '?e=' + error
```

Any idea of what could be going on?

Thanks very much in advance and have a nice weekend!

Pablo

edit: The part of the function:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
   var error = dbErrorHandler(err)
   return res.redirect('/app/editar/' + username + '?e=' + error)
  }
  return res.redirect('/app/editar/' + username + '/?suc=upsuccess')
})
```

and here is dbErrorHandler:

```
function dbErrorHandler(err) {
  console.log('There is been an error' + err)
  if (String(err).indexOf('email_1') !== -1)
    return 'eexists'

  return 'unknown'
}
```

Further tips regarding my code are very welcome.

Comment: Include the whole function that contains the redirect please.

Comment: Where does `username` come from?

Comment: username comes from the headers.referer. Is declared on top of the main function.